# JSX element attributes type [...] may not be a union type

Tags: typescript, reactjs

In Typescript 2.1, when attempting the following:

```
// address.tsx
...
interface Address {
  street: string;
  country: string;
}

interface CanadianAddress extends Address {
  postalCode: string;
}

interface AmericanAddress extends Address {
  zipCode: string;
}

type Properties = AmericanAddress | CanadianAddress'

function isAmerican(address: Properties) address is AmericanAddress {
 return 'zipCode' in address;
}

export class Address extends React.Component<Properties, void> {
  public render() {
    let isAmerican = isAmerican(this.props.address);
    ...
  }
}

// map.tsx
...
let rootDiv = document.createElement('root')l
ReactDOM.render(<Address postalCode='T1B 0L3' />, rootDiv);
```

The follow error occurs at compile time:

> error TS2600: JSX element attributes type '({ children?: ReactNode; } & AmericanAddress) | ({ children?: ReactNode; } & CanadianAddress' may not be a union type.

I'm wondering why this isn't supported, and how I can I accomplish this without having an overly-complicated set of properties to specify?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13526

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not possible, all I could find is this by @RyanCavanaugh:

> we don't really correctly support the JSX Attributes type being a
>   union type

In the issue: [Allow JSX element attributes type to be an intersection](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4362#issuecomment-132742717).

A way to deal with this is to have two different components which are subclasses of `Address`:

```
interface AddressProperties {
    street: string;
    country: string;
}

interface CanadianAddressProperties extends AddressProperties {
    postalCode: string;
}

interface AmericanAddressProperties extends AddressProperties {
    zipCode: string;
}

abstract class Address<P extends AddressProperties> extends React.Component<P, void> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <div className={ this.getClassName() + " address"}>
                <div><span>Street:</span><span>{ this.props.street }</span></div>
                <div><span>Country:</span><span>{ this.props.country }</span></div>
                {  }
            </div>
        );
    }

    protected abstract getClassName(): string;
    protected abstract getCountryElements(): JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

class CanadianAddress extends Address<CanadianAddressProperties> {
    protected getClassName(): string {
        return "canadian";
    }

    protected getCountryElements(): JSX.Element {
        return <div><span>Postal Code:</span><span>{ this.props.postalCode }</span></div>;
    }
}

class AmericanAddress extends Address<AmericanAddressProperties> {
    protected getClassName(): string {
        return "american";
    }

    protected getCountryElements(): JSX.Element {
        return <div><span>Zip Code:</span><span>{ this.props.zipCode }</span></div>;
    }
}
```

If the only change between the two is the `zipCode`/`postalCode` then it might be an overkill, but if there are more differences then it makes sense to separate the two into different components.

Otherwise you'll need to just have `postalCode` and `zipCode` as optional in the `AddressProperties`.